# How to make JTextArea fit whole panel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, components, jtextarea

How to fit Jtextarea to the panel size with no space between th edges?

Why has this Component such strange behaviour? I mean, I set size of it to, let' say, JTextArea(10,10), but I can type more characters in one line than 10. Why is that?

//sorry for my bad english

Comment: *"How to fit Jtextarea to the panel size with no space between th edges?"* - Use a `BoderLayout` - better yet, wrap it in a `JScrollPane` and then add it to container using `BorderLayout`

Comment: *"Why has this Component such strange behaviour?"* - It's not strange, this is how it works.  `JTextArea(10,10)` is a simplified way in which the API can calculate the preferred size of the text area based on the current font preferences, but these are simply "guides" to help layout managers to make decisions about how best to lay it out, it's not a restriction to the size of the component (unless the layout manager decides it is) - this is just how the API works

Comment: Maybe a better place to start would be [How to Use Text Areas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html), [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html), [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and the [JavaDocs for `JTextArea`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html)